Comparing Different weeks from different years based of when the campaign is starting PowerBI
I am looking to have a column or a method of comparison in PowerBI based on the following example: In 2023 I had a Campaign that started in week 26 of the year and ended in week 33 and the same campaign started in 2024 on week 3 and has ended in week 10. What I want to do is that I want to have some sort of a slicer in which I can select First week of a campaign or 2nd or the first 3 weeks of the campaign and to see the difference between those weeks in year 2023 and 2024 based on when the campaign started.
I have 2 separate databases from 2023 and 2024, they are linked eachother based on the campaign, also created a distinct table with weeks of the year (1-52) and are liked together as well with the 2023 2024. From here I can compare week 1 from 2023 with week 1 from 2024 and so forth, however I can't find a solution to compare The week by week of the campaign witch is starting in week 3 on 2024 with the first week of the campaign that has started in week 26 in 2023.

You need to add a column to your fact table that "normalizes" the data by calculating the difference between the earliest date in the campaign (day zero) with the current date. Then you will be comparing apples to apples.
